# Includes HTML template, not rendering Django content

Tags: html, django

I have created a special offers page which is meant to form as a carousel. I have created this HTML file in my `products/templates/products/includes/special_offers.html` folder.

I have then added {% include products/includes/special_offers.html %} on the appropriate page.

When I vew that page, everything before my for loop is appearing. I cannot get content within the for loop to appear and I have no idea why.

I'm using a similar for loop on my products page already and it's working fine. I must be missing some piece of the puzzle. I've tried remove most of the HTML and just render a product image but no joy. Anyone able to spot anything? I've tested quite a bit to no avail. What would cause code that works on 1 page, but not on the other page?

HTML

```
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<section class="container">
    <hr>
    <h2 class="sub-title">Special Offers</h2>
    <div class="container my-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 m-auto">
                <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                    {% for product in products %}
                    <p>HELLO</p>
                        <div class="card card-owl h-100 border-0">
                            {% if product.image %}
                            <a href="{% url 'product_detail' product.id %}">
                                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid w-75 product-img" src="{{ product.image.url }}" alt="{{ product.name }} Image">
                            </a>
                            {% else %}
                            <a href="{% url 'product_detail' product.id %}">
                                <img class="card-img-top img-fluid w-75 product-img" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}noimage.png" alt="{{ product.name }} Image">
                            </a>
                            {% endif %}
                            <div class="card-body pb-0">
                                <p class="mb-0">{{ product.name }}</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card-footer bg-white pt-0 border-0 text-left">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col">
                                        {% if product.sale_price %}
                                        <p class="lead mb-0 text-left font-weight-bold line-through">€{{ product.sale_price }}</p>
                                        <p class="lead mb-0 text-left font-weight-bold text-success">€{{ product.price }}</p>
                                        {% else %}
                                        <p class="lead mb-0 text-left font-weight-bold">€{{ product.price }}</p>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        {% if product.category %}
                                        <p class="small mt-1 mb-0">
                                            <a class="text-muted" href="{% url 'products' %}?category={{ product.category.name | urlencode }}">
                                                <i class="fa regular fa-clock interactive-color"></i> {{ product.category.friendly_name }}
                                            </a>
                                        </p>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        {% if product.special_offers %}
                                        <p class="small mt-1 mb-0">
                                            <a class="text-muted" href="{% url 'products' %}?special_offers={{ product.special_offers }}">
                                                <i class="fas fa-tag mr-1 interactive-color"></i> {{ product.special_offers }}
                                            </a>
                                        </p>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        {% if product.rating %}
                                            <small class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-star mr-1"></i>{{ product.rating }} / 5</small>
                                        {% else %}
                                            <small class="text-muted">No Rating</small>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        <div>
                                            <a href="{% url 'product_detail' product.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-black rounded-0 mt-2 bg-warning">Buy Now</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
{% endblock content %}
{% block postloadjs %}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
        
            nav: true,
            autoplay: true,
            autoPlaySpeed: 5000,
            autoPlayTimeout: 5000,
            autoplayHoverPause: true,
            responsive: {
                0: {
                    items: 1
                },
                600: {
                    items: 2
                },
                1000: {
                    items: 3
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

views.py

```
def all_products(request):
    """ 
    A view to show all products, including sorting and search queries 
    """

    products = Product.objects.all()
    query = None
    categories = None
    sort = None
    direction = None
    special_offers = None

    if request.GET:
        if 'sort' in request.GET:
            sortkey = request.GET['sort']
            sort = sortkey
            if sortkey == 'name':
                sortkey = 'lower_name'
                products = products.annotate(lower_name=Lower('name'))
            if sortkey == 'category':
                sortkey = 'category__name'
            if sortkey == 'special_offers':
                sortkey = 'special_offers__name'
            if 'direction' in request.GET:
                direction = request.GET['direction']
                if direction == 'desc':
                    sortkey = f'-{sortkey}'
            products = products.order_by(sortkey)

        if 'category' in request.GET:
            categories = request.GET['category'].split(',')
            products = products.filter(category__name__in=categories)
            categories = Category.objects.filter(name__in=categories)
    
        if 'special_offers' in request.GET:
            special_offers = request.GET['special_offers'].split(',')
            products = products.filter(special_offers__name__in=special_offers)
            special_offers = SpecialOffers.objects.filter(name__in=special_offers)

    if request.GET:
        if 'q' in request.GET:
            query = request.GET['q']
            if not query:
                messages.error(request, "You didn't enter a search criteria")
                return redirect(reverse('products'))
            
            queries = Q(name__icontains=query) | Q(description__icontains=query)
            products = products.filter(queries)

    current_sorting = f'{sort}_{direction}'

    context = {
        'products': products,
        'search_term': query,
        'current_categories': categories,
        'current_sorting': current_sorting,
        'current_special_offers': special_offers,
    }

    return render(request, 'products/products.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.all_products, name='products'),
    path('<int:product_id>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
    path('add/', views.add_product, name='add_product'),
    path('edit/<int:product_id>/', views.edit_product, name='edit_product'),
    path('delete/<int:product_id>/', views.delete_product, name='delete_product'),
]
```

Comment: Share the HTML where you are using {% include products/includes/special_offers.html %} and loop both

Comment: @vinita-sonakiya, I spent the day deploying and setting up stripe. Looking back into this issue now. I'm not sure what you mean by loop both? I've added the includes url to the logout page. I've included the logout.html code above. It's just an allauth logout page.

Comment: If everything _before_ the loop is rendering, I'd suspect that the context variable you're trying to loop through is empty. Check that your context variable names are the same as what's being passed from the view, or use `{% include ... with x=y %}` if you need to coerce the variable names.